# html / classic asp project and need to add temporary messages, what tag is safe to put them after

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, asp-classic

I have an html / classic asp project and need to add temporary messages for public display on the web page.

Is there a tag that is always safe to put them after?

I tried putting them after `<HEAD>` which allowed lots of pages to be changed quickly in VS, but it interfered with the functionality big time.

Is it safe to put them after the `<HTML>` tag?

Or does one have to put it just before the `</HTML>` tag?

Or is there some other place?

I am using the following format:

```
<p><b><span>Server message</span></b> </p>
```

Comment: Looks like your post is missing some text.  What tags have you tried?

Comment: Legally, `<p>`-s must be between the `<body>` and `</body>` tags. If you put them between `<head>` and `</head>`, then it'll depend on the browser whether and how they're displayed, and depending on your css, it could look horrible or barely-acceptable. Can you clarify whether you need these messages to be visible in the browser? If not, you can use html comments (`<!-- -->`) anywhere, and they will be visible in the page source. Also, what exactly do you mean by "interfered with the functionality big time"?

Comment: The message is similar to "server will be down for maintenance" and is for actual visitors

Comment: was looking for a general solution, but it appears I'll have to do each page separately. The pages "include" other pages, and the functionality stops working if the message is not put in the correct place. This is somewhat alarming, Alternatively, if I move the message from top to bottom, the functionality works, but the message itself doesn't display at all. Thus, what should be a simple task has become way too complicated. I'll probably have to move the message to the files that are "included" which I was hoping not to have to do, but such is life.

Comment: The approach of editing the include file does indeed work in my case.  I was hoping to just do a massive search and replace to do all files at once, but at least in my case this will not work.   Knowing that <p> must be within <body> was very useful to this cause.

Comment: I edited question for clarity, therefore some of the discussion is now moot, but made sense when added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What tags have you used? And temporary messages for whom?

If you're talking about developers then you could simply put in comment blocks (as pointed out by Martha):

```html
<!-- -->
```

For users, then the information should appear in the body text using whatever format you require (e.g. a hidden `div` that can be displayed and hidden again using JavaScript). For instance, in one of my systems, I use the following...

```html
<%if now() < #21-Jul-2015 21:00:00# then%>
    <div id="notifications">
        <h1>Very Important - Please Read:</h1>
        <p>This is a server message.</p>
        <a onClick="hideMessage();" 
           style="float:right;margin:2px; padding: 4px 8px;; border: 1px solid darkgreen; 
           background-color: lightgreen; color: darkgreen; cursor: pointer;">
            <img src="images/tick.png" /> Ok! Got it!
        </a>
    </div>
<%end if%>
```

For bots or other analysis mediums, you should consider using `meta` tags in the head of the page:

```html
<meta name="message" content="Whatever you want" />
```

The problem is, your question is possibly [too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) at the moment, you may want to fine tune it.

### Further

To expand this process you could create Application level variables in your `global.asa`:

```vbs
Sub Application_OnStart()
    Application("MESSAGE_DATETIME") = #22-Jul-2015#
    Application("MESSAGE_TITLE") = "Maintenance"
    Application("MESSAGE_DETAIL") = "Server down for maintenance."
End Sub
```

Create a new file with just a section in to display the message, similar to what I showed you above.  In each of your files thereafter, put an include in the body where you want the message to appear, so you don't have to repeat everything...

```
<!-- #include file="includes/serverMessages.asp" -->
```

Far easier than having to introduce loads of redundancy throughout your code.

Comment: The message is similar to "server will be down for maintenance" and is for actual visitors.

Comment: I was looking for a general solution, but it appears I'll have to do each page separately.  The pages "include" other pages, and the functionality stops working if the message is not put in the correct place.  This is somewhat alarming,  Alternatively, if I move the message from top to bottom, the functionality works, but the message itself doesn't display at all.  Thus, what should be a simple task has become way too complicated.  I'll probably have to move the message to the files that are "included" which I was hoping not to have to do, but such is life.

Comment: The approach of editing the include file does indeed work in my case. I was hoping to just do a massive search and replace to do all files at once, but at least in my case this will not work. Knowing that <p> must be within <body> was very useful to this cause

Comment: I edited question for clarity, therefore some of the discussion is now moot, but made sense when added.

Comment: @JosephDoggie: I've expanded the answer to help you.  Sub-note: If you follow the process of using the global.asa like this, you only have to edit the text and date without searching through the includes etc.  Also, once the global.asa is updated this causes a refresh so that the application *kind of* recycles the pool.